# mutable set object as dictionary key in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

in python documentation it's said that "set type is mutable ....  Since it is mutable, it has no hash value and cannot be used as either a dictionary key or as an element of another set" unlike its frozenset that is immutable object. But when i try :

```
>>> dict(zip(set(['a', 'b', 'c']), [1, 2, 3]))
>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

also

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(set([1, 2, 3, 4]))
>>> {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}
```

why that the mutable set object (built in set function) can be used as dictionary keys? Thanks for the explanation

Comment: The `set` is not used as dictionary keys, the keys are string values as you can see

Comment: `zip()` creates tuples likes `[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands but how about this dict.fromkeys(set([1, 2, 3, 4])) it's result dictionary {1:None, 2:None, 3:None, 4:None} ....

Comment: In that case the integers are the keys,  try `dict([(set(),1)])`

Comment: @Chris_Rands can you figure out how to make mutable set object cannot be used as dictionary keys (may be it should raise KeyError... cause i can't still figure out how to make it happends, type({1, 2, 3, 4}) is set... thank you..

Comment: Try my example it raises `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`, you don't want to raise a key error, a key error is raised when *accessing* a dict, not *creating* one

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` constructor can take an iterable (such as a `set`) and create from it the dictionary. Your first expression doesn't even pass a set to the `dict`.

First expression evaluates to something similar to (see comments)

```
dict(zip(set(['a', 'b', 'c']), [1, 2, 3])) => 
dict([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)])
```

which has nothing to do with a `set`. The second expression becomes

```
dict.fromkeys(set(set([1, 2, 3, 4])) =>
dict.fromkeys(set([1, 2, 3, 4])) =
```

which is no different than using

```
dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

as `fromkeys` will just iterate the argument.
Also, the second `set` is redundant (if you wanted a set containing a set set you needed `set([set(...)])`.

What you wanted is:

```
>>> {set((1,2,3)): 4}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

or

```
>>> dict([(set([1]),1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: First expression may evaluate differently since sets are not ordered

Comment: @Chris_Rands correct, but is that nuance you think belongs in this answer? Also, from Python 3 I think the order is guaranteed if no deletions happen (given the same set).

Comment: The order is not guaranteed for Python 3 at all, maybe you're thinking of dicts, but that's only guaranteed from Python 3.7

Comment: @Chris_Rands Ah, indeed you're right. Anyway, I softened my wording and pointed to the comments.

Comment: @kabanus yes this is what i wanted how to raise exception since mutable set object cannot used as dictionary key... thanks